# Equivalence relations and the axiom of choice

Tags: set-theory, axiom-of-choice

Let $X,Y$ be two sets and  $f:X\rightarrow Y$ a function. If we  define an equivalence relation $\sim$ on $X$ and we assume that if $x_1\sim x_2$ then $f(x_1)=f(x_2)$, we can define a function
$\overline f:X/_\sim\rightarrow Y$ such that $\overline f([x]):=f(x)$. Practically if we have a set of representatives $R$ for the relation $\sim$, then we completely "know" the function $\overline f$. But if we don't assume the axiom of choice, the set $R$ can be empty, is it right?

Comment: "algebra-precalculus" seems an odd tag for a question about the Axiom of Choice.

Comment: edited, many thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to define $\bar{f}$ without the Axiom of Choice?

Comment: Yes I'm asking if $\overline f$ exists without assuming the axiom of choice.

Comment: @Galoisfan: my answer explains that it does

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We may not have a set of representatives without the axiom of choice. That doesn't mean the set of representatives is empty, it just means it does not exist - there is no set that satisfies the definition of a set of representatives for $X/\sim$.

But we do not need a set of representatives to define the function $\bar f$ in ZF. It can be defined as follows:
$$
\bar f (C) = y \Leftrightarrow (\forall x \in C)[f(x) =y]
$$
In other words, $\bar f$ is the set of pairs $(C,y)$ where $C \in X/\sim$ and $(\forall x \in C)[f(x) = y]$. That definition of $\bar f$ works in ZF without the axiom of choice. Rather than using representatives for the equivalence classes, we can just use the equivalence classes themselves.

In case you are worried about $X/\sim$ itself, it is definable as
$$
\{ C \subseteq X : (\exists z)(\forall y)[y \in C \leftrightarrow (y \in X \land y \sim z)]\}$$

Comment: I don't know if the following remark is helpful: by adopting a more "functional" perspective one could say that to give a set of representatives is to give a function $r \colon X/{\sim} \to X$ right inverse to the projection $X \to X/{\sim}, x \mapsto [x]$. One can then define $\bar{f} = f \circ r$ and check that $\bar{f}$ is independent of the choice of $r$. You show that the detour back to $X$ is unnecessary for establishing the existence of $\bar{f}$.

Answer (score 4):

This is essentially as saying that every $f\colon X\to Y$ can be restricted to some $R\subseteq X$, and the restriction is an injective function with the same range as $f$.

The above is equivalent to the axiom of choice, so whenever the axiom of choice fails this principle must fail *somewhere* as well.

It should be pointed out, however, that the set of equivalence classes still exists. The set of representatives (to which you want to restrict the function to) does not. For example $\mathbb{R/Q}$ always exists, but if all sets are measurable then you cannot define a Vitali set, which is that system of representatives.

Comment: And this marks my 200th answer on [axiom-of-choice].

Comment: Congrats. How long did that take?

Comment: I started meddling seriously about topics of choice two years ago. I may have gathered a couple of answers before that, but roughly two years ago I began taking it more seriously.

Comment: Congrats on the gold! Too bad Brian got his bronze badge a while ago.

Comment: @Arthur: Yeah... Good luck to Vera/congratulation to you both, by the way.

Comment: Thanks, Asaf.  We're still waiting... less and less patiently as the days pass.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, if you have a function $f:X\to Y$ then you completely know the function if you define the equivalence relation $x~x'$ if $f(x)=f(x')$, choosing a representative from each equivalence class and recording the value of $f$ on each representative (notice that this is slightly more accurate than the original statement in the question). Without the axiom of choice, or some extra knowledge of the domain of $f$ and/or $f$ itself, there is no guarantee that the set of all representatives exists.